# Spring Security 403 Error While Trying To Add a New User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been trying to add a create method to my spring boot security app but, when I use post mapping I get that error. Also, my id is auto-incremented in db. I am not sure but maybe the error is because of it. I don't know how to write an auto-incremented value in the request body.

```
{"timestamp":"2020-08- 
   23T00:43:31.062+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"","path":"/createUser"}
The body that i am trying to post:
{
    "id": 3,
    "userName": "Adminn",
    "password": "pss",
    "active": true,
    "role": "ROLE_ADMIN"
}
```

Request Body for Post Mapping
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqoD0.png

My home resource class

```
package io.javabrains.springsecurity.jpa;

@RestController
public class HomeResource {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@GetMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return ("<h1>Welcome</h1>");
}

@GetMapping("/user")
public String user() {
    return ("Welcome User");
}

@GetMapping("/admin")
public String admin() {
    return ("<h1>Welcome Admin</h1>");
}


@GetMapping("/users/{id}")  
public Optional<User> retriveUser(@PathVariable int id)  
{  
    return userRepo.findById(id);
    
}  

@PostMapping("/createUser")
public void createUser(@RequestBody User myuser) {
    
    User savedUser=userRepo.save(myuser);
     
}
/*@GetMapping("/createUser") // it is working
public String addUser() {
    User newuser= new User();
    newuser.setUserName("new");
    newuser.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("pass"));
    newuser.setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
    newuser.setActive(true);
    userRepo.save(newuser);
    
    return  "user booked";
}*/

}
```

My Spring App Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
public class SpringsecurityApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

@Autowired
 UserRepository userRepository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringsecurityApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Application Running.");
    User adminUser= new User();
    adminUser.setUserName("Admin");
    adminUser.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("pass"));
    adminUser.setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
    adminUser.setActive(true);
    userRepository.save(adminUser);
    User newUser= new User();
    newUser.setUserName("User");
    newUser.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("pass"));
    newUser.setRole("ROLE_USER");
    newUser.setActive(true);
    userRepository.save(newUser);
}

}
```

User Class

```
 package io.javabrains.springsecurity.jpa.models;
    @Entity
    @Table(name="app_user")
    public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private String role;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    }
```

Security Config Class

```
 package io.javabrains.springsecurity.jpa;
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder ()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
            .antMatchers("/","/createUser").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin();
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because CSRF protection for state-changing HTTP verbs, such as POST, is enabled by default. You can either disable it or include CSRF token in your web page, and subsequently in your HTTP request.

Comment: I added these to my code and worked.                                                                                                   'http.csrf().disable();
         http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
         http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
         http.authorizeRequests()
                 .anyRequest()
                 .authenticated()
                 .and(); '

Answer (score 0):

What if you modify your code this way:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/createUser").permitAll()
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all is a bad practice try to map the JSON request to an entity class. First you should use a DTO class.
Do that first and see what happend